# facebook payments disputes callback

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Can anybody tell how can I handle facebook payments disputes callback in php? Code is preferable. I am handling disputes in my app and I have gone through this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/disputesrefunds/

when a user disputes an order, a realtime update is sent to the developer specified URL with the associated payment_id. But I dont know in which format I will receive it and I dont know how to handle disputes ahead in the code.